# ui.grid A promise was not returned when saveRow event was raised, either nobody is listening to event, or event handler did not return a promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using `ui.grid` and stuck with `celledit` functionality. The row gets saved in DB, but shows an error as give below.

```
angular.min.js:2 A promise was not returned when saveRow event was raised, either nobody is listening to event, or event handler did not return a promise
```

Controller:

```
$scope.saveRow = function( rowEntity ) {
    // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
    //var promise = $q.defer();
    ExpService.insertExp(rowEntity);
    /*console.log(rowEntity);
    $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise( rowEntity, promise.promise );
    promise.resolve();*/
};

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    // set gridApi on scope
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);
};
```

ExpService:

```
var exp={};
exp.insertExp = function(insData){
    return $http.post(config.expInsertURL, insData).then(function(repos){
        return repos.data;
    },function(error){
        alert("Error happened while getting response \n" + error);
        return "";
    });
}
return exp;
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue? In particular, I don't understand why do we need a `promise` in that function, even after reading the `ui.grid` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a valid promise associated with row save. From the [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.rowEdit.api:PublicApi) for setSavePromise:

> Sets the promise associated with the row save, **mandatory** that the
>   saveRow event handler calls this method somewhere before returning.

Controller:

```
$scope.saveRow = function( rowEntity ) {
    var promise = ExpService.insertExp( rowEntity );
    $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise( rowEntity, promise );
};
```